# Passing Data from Parent component to Dialog (Reactive forms)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Wondering if you can explain the method and best practices to me on how to go about passing data from my angular mat-table to a dialog that pops up on click to edit. The functionality that I want implemented, is on click of this show details button in my mat-table, I want the dialog to pop up and then the fields in the pop up to show the information from the table (parent) that was clicked. (The pop up functionality is already working perfectly)
The dialog is a Reactive form.

I have been messing around with  the setValue() method in ngOnInit, just getting familiar, but I realize that that is just a fraction of what i'm trying to accomplish. Any suggestions or knowledge? Thanks in advance.

here is the parent: firewallscreated.component.ts

```
openDialog() {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManageFwxComponent, {
  data: {
    theData: "testing",
  },
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
  console.log("The dialog was closed");
});}}
```

Above is the way that I am opening the dialog, with the component that I want popping up as a parameter passed in.

Below is the child component (popup) with the reactive form which field values I want to set when show details button is clicked from the parent component with the information from that table.

The child component: manage-fwx.component.ts:

```
export class ManageFwxComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
private fb: FormBuilder,
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ManageFwxComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
ngOnInit(): void {}

newFwxEdit = this.fb.group({
fwxid: ["", Validators.required],
securityPlan: ["", Validators.required],
fireWall: ["", Validators.required],
fwxDescription: ["", Validators.required],
requesterComments: [""],
requesterContactInfo: [""],
sourceIPs: ["", Validators.required],
destinationIPs: ["", Validators.required],
tcpPorts: ["", Validators.required],
udpPorts: ["", Validators.required],
protocolAndPorts: ["", Validators.required],});
```

Trying to be as detailed and within guidelines as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. All you need is to create an `interface` for the data you want to pass instead of `any`. The reason we want to use `interface` instead of `any` is because we want to leverage the type system in TypeScript. Type system helps the compiler catches bug during compile time. It also help with intelliSense.

The official way is to pass the `data` when you open the dialog. Then in the dialog(child), you need to use injection token via `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: YOUR_DATA_TYPE`. This injection token makes sure that once the dialog(child) is open, it will have access to the data passed from the parent.

#### manage-fwx.component.ts

```js
// ...import dependencies here.


export interface FirewallData {
  fwxid: number;
  securityPlan: string;
  fireWall: string;
  fwxDescription: string;

  //... the rest of data you need.
}

@Component({
 ...
})
export class ManageFwxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ManageFwxComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: FirewallData){
  }

  public ngOninit() {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.fwxid);
  }
}
```

#### firewallscreated.component.ts

```js
@Component({
 ...
})
export class FirewallsCreated {

  public openDialog() {

    const data: FirewallData = {
      fwxid: 1,
      securityPlan: 'plan',
      //... add the rest here.
    };

    const config = { data = data };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ManageFwxComponent, config);
  }

}
```